# Publish Elm19 package, which first version was published as 18 package at a time Elm19 was already out

Tags: elm, package-management

Some time after the release of Elm19 I published a library, which I needed for an Elm18 code base: `thought2/elm-wikimedia-commons`.
This worked well, it's listed in the community driven Elm18 package database: https://dmy.github.io/elm-0.18-packages/, can be installed and all good. Except the fact that the documentation is not shown in the package details, but that I heard is a known bug there. (But still I think this is very bad)

But the main problem is now, how to migrate the library to Elm 19: The actual migration steps are done and live in the master branch of the repo: http://github.com/thought2/elm-wikimedia-commons

The Elm18 versions proceeded to `1.1.0` in the meanwhile and after the migration there had to be done an API change, so I'd assume the latest version to become `2.0.0`. If I add this to `elm.json`, the command `elm publish` tells me that this would be the first version and I should change this. Which is not right.

After a bit of research, I found out that the package (among other 18 ones that have been published in the same time period) is not listed in this json: https://package.elm-lang.org/all-packages This should contain all packages regardless of versions.

Any ideas what to do? This is really blocking my development, as I'm stuck in both lands now: 18 and 19. Would appreciate a lot if someone has some hints or solutions for me!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to mess with the version number specified in elm.json.
If you set it back to the version of the package that is already published and run `elm bump` the elm program will look at the changes you've made to the package's API and set the new version accordingly.

Looking at https://github.com/thought2/elm-wikimedia-commons it doesn't look like any of your upgrade changes were breaking changes to your package API so the version won't be a 2.x.x, it will be a 1.x.x.

You'll need to remove the 2.0.0 git tag as well and instead add a tag for the version that `elm bump` tells you that your package is.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. However, I think it does not hit the point. whatever version I put to the elm.json, `elm bump` or `elm publish` insists that it's the first version. Whether the changes where major or not, does not matter - it should definitely be something above 1.1.0. The problem is that the tool does not find the older versions as it's not listed in the JSON as described above.

Comment: i think that's good and bad news. The bad is that it may be hard for 0.18 users to find your code, but the good is that you can publish the 0.19 version as 1.0.0